# PHP Sessions not transferring after forms and redirects

Tags: php, session

I have secured pages that all check for a set session variable to determine logged in users, pretty standard stuff.  Where I run into problems is when I submit form information to a backend page that will process that data and then redirect to a success/failure confirmation page.  In that time the session gets lost, at least the session with the variable.  The session is still around because I can manually navigate to a secured page after and it works.  Just auto redirects from a backend page to a secured page or a link on one of the unsecured pages after a redirect from the backend will fail.  It may or may not be related, but after visiting multiple secured pages or doing one of the operations that use the problematic backend pages, there are two session cookies on my computer from the domain-- one registered to domain.com and the other to www.domain.com.  At the end of my wits about this, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems here, but they're related.

The first is that you seem to be bouncing between secured (`https://`) and un-secured (`http://`) pages. Cookies aren't supposed to be shared between those, so that's why your session appears to break (PHP sets a cookie with the session ID).

The other is closely related and that is sharing between `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`. Cookies can share in one direction, but not the other. Don't worry about which: just pick one hostname and stick with it. Then check that you're setting the session's cookie domain to the correct one.

Comment: I should note, that I mispoke when I said secured, I did not mean to imply HTTPS secured, just that the pages are checking the user's session status on load.  The issue with the two sessions is it is unclear why there are two in the first place.  The calls are all the same session_start() calls, but still there end up being two different cookies.

Comment: Perhaps one of your intermediate pages isn't actually doing the `session_start()`. Or is trying to do it after output has been emitted.

Comment: Taking one five page cycle for example, all pages start a session.  This would be login page -> main secured page -> backside action page -> success page -> back to main page, two different sessions as mentioned get created.  The domain.com without www seems to pop up around step 3, on the php page the user will never see that just processes the data.  This I tested by securing step 4 with the same test for the user variables as used on the rest of the site.

Comment: Then one of your posts or redirects is going to `domain.com` instead of to `www.domain.com`.

Comment: Would relative path names resolve as www.domain.com or domain.com?

Comment: Relative paths shouldn't change the domain.

Comment: Beautiful suggestion about the redirects, I was not aware that my redirects were going to http://domain.com and that seems to have fixed the problem across the entire site.  This problem has been haunting me for weeks during the development of this app.  Also the relative paths do not seem to cause any problems with the sessions, only when I explicitly change from www.domain.com to domain.com or the other way around.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must call `session_start()` from your PHP page before you output anything, preferably at the start of the page.

If the session has been already created, it will resume it for that page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php